# Docker: Keep a container from starting automatically

Tags: 15.10, docker

I made a simple typo when adding a container in Ubuntu 15.10 using docker's run command (docker run --restart=always) now the container boots twice and listens on two different ports. My question is, how remove the unwanted instance from starting automatically.

Here is an example of what i am talking about.

```
PORTS                   NAMES
0.0.0.0:22000->22/tcp   prickly_colden
0.0.0.0:2200->22/tcp    grave_meninsky
```

Thanks to anyone who can help,

Mike

Answer (score 4):

After some research, I was able to figure it out...

First, Inspect the restart policy of the container (optional) by typing

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}' 'your container name'
```

Second, remove the mistaken container instance by running this command...

```
docker rm -f 'your container name'
```

Third, restart the container with a different policy if needed...

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --restart=on-failure:10 'Your Image Name'
```

Fourth, reboot and the container should be gone!

Mike

More Information:

http://www.brandpending.com/blog/2014/11/21/setting-and-re-setting-the-restart-behaviour-of-a-docker-container

Comment: Looks like the recommended post link has vanished and couldn't find any cached version. Therefore, I'll suggest this substitute link which has more-or-less the same informative content, via the archived link for posterity: [https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy](https://web.archive.org/web/20231128054416/https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy)